IIS Reverse Proxy Configuration for Node.js Backend
I have tried every possible way to deploy my node js app in the IIS, I have used reserve proxy, my backend is successfully running in locally windows server 2019 VPS. Now after my domain like www.thediamlaundry.com/backend i want to direct to backend route and get all data as well as be able to access all express route from the backend. but i am unable to do this,
www.thediamlaundry.com/backend This just gives me react frontend file navbar and footer rather then showing my data which i have got from the api,
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyBackend" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^backend/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:2000/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>   

I have done every possible method like allowing incoming port and other, i am stuck in this, please help me to get solve this, i would really appreciate.

This is a typical issue because you forgot to loose the front end rewrite rule on /backend. Revise that and then you will get started on the right track.

Thanks Lex Li for your answer ! Lex Li can you please explain where i made this mistake because i am really unable to find what i am missing! please

No one can easily tell where you misconfigured the server, as it can be in applicationHost.config or any other web.config. That's why this site is not that helpful for beginners. You will have to learn the configuration system bit and bit and help yourself out, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/the-configuration-system-in-iis-7 if you don't want to hire an experienced coach or buy commercial support services.

When you deploy your app in local windows server, what path do you use to request/get the API data? According to your rewrite rules, the request address you provide will be rewritten to http://localhost:2000/. This does not seem to be a complete API request address. Maybe you are missing the {R:1} part?

Hi Xudong Peng thanks for your interest in this question! I use path something like http://localhost:2000/api/auth/getUsers or any other route eg (http://localhost:2000/api/getOrders, http://localhost:2000/api/getAllPriceListItems) and so on according to express routes. this is my route app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api", priceRoutes);
app.use("/api", orderRoutes);
app.use("/api", serviceRoutes)
app.use("/api", notificationRoutes) so how should i write  rules please guide me !

Modify the action url, like this: <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:2000/api/{R:1}" />. And try to access www.thediamlaundry.com/backend/getOrders to check if you can get the data of this API. Maybe you can also simply refer to this case.

xudong peng i have create backend as a subdirectory from the frontend ! my folder structure is like wwwroot -> thediamlaundry (Frontend files + web.config) -> backend (web.config like you teach me) but i am just getting react navbar and footer rather than directing to backend

my web.config from frontend files 

<system.webServer>







</system.webServer>


my web.config from backend 
<system.webServer>








</system.webServer>


I'm not sure what you are doing, what I mentioned above refers to modifying the ReverseProxyBackend rule section in Web.Config. In addition, I think your main problem is that the request address cannot be rewritten to the correct API request address. The (.*) in the "match" part of the rule corresponds to {R:1} in the "action". In your case, this part (i.e. your api method name) is not included.
